# multi_query error catching

Tags: php, multi-query

I searched quite a lot via Google about this but there aren't any answers which help me - or I just couldn't find the solution by myself.

This is my problem: I have a large multi_query (about 50+ subsequent queries), which I execute. If I do understand the manual correct I have to free the results of a `multi_query()` because for each subsequent query the php interpreter will return at least an "ok" as an result or something like this - and I have to free it first. Is this correct or I understood anything wrong here?

I'm currently trying this to free `multi_query` results:

```
$Result = $this->Connect->multi_query($Query);
                if($Result !== false) {
                    // Query was ok - got result
                        while ($this->Connect->more_results() && $this->Connect->next_result());
                }
                    else {
                        // If the query failed
                        $this->Valid = false;
                    array_push($this->SQLErrors,$this->Connect->error);
                    return false;
                }
```

Is this correct and if it is - why? If im only using `while($this->Connect->next_result())` it throws me errors like `"Strict Standards: there is no next result set"`.

How do I catch errors? By executing a `multi_query` out of 50 subsequent small queries i want to be able to have something like `$ErrorStack[3] = "Mysql Error: ..."`; which means my 3rd Subsequent Query failed. How do I do this?